# Removing / Editing Desktop Right Click Actions 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, icons

I would like to remove the 'Organize Desktop by Name' action, or at least edit the desktop right click menu to put an indent between 'paste' and 'Organize Desktop by Name', so I don't keep mucking up my desktop icon layout when I missclick and hit the latter when intending to hit the former.

Nautilus actions helps define and add new actions, but I've been unable to use it to remove already existing actions.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to suppress it would be take a copy of the source code, remove the line(s)

```
if (FM_IS_DESKTOP_ICON_VIEW (view))
{
    gtk_action_set_label (action, _("_Organize Desktop by Name"));
}
```

and re-compile/install your own copy of [Caja](https://github.com/mate-desktop/caja/blob/ad67fbbf8d747845089c24e3500bb8e03acd5adf/src/file-manager/fm-icon-view.c#L788-L791)

Although, another perspective -- there should be space around the separator (dark line) in the theme, which would add padding around "Open in Terminal" amongst other options, but it will only be available in the 19.10.

To use the updated Ambiant-MATE theme, [get a copy of the latest ubuntu-mate-artwork repository](https://github.com/ubuntu-mate/ubuntu-mate-artwork/archive/master.zip) and copy the contents of usr/share/themes/ to ~/.local/share/themes (it's a hidden folder in your home directory, press CTRL+H to toggle them). That separator should help when you next miss by a few pixels

Comment: This happened again, and I'm about to go legit crazy. There must be a way to at least lock desktop icon positions in place. Or put an indent between paste and organize desktop by name.